# knote/sticky note widget text location

Tags: kde, plasma, widgets

I had several note widgets on Plasma Desktop. Where are the notes saved? I have a problem with plasma-desktop and it is not run. But I need the notes. Where can I find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Sticky notes

The information is saved: `~/.kde/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc`

[image]

### Leave a Note

The 'Leave a Note' is using the Knotes. The Knotes information `~/.kde/share/apps/knotes/notes.ics`

[image]

Comment: Do know a way to make it into something more readable (If plasma is not isntalled)?

Answer (score 18):

KDE 5 stores notes in the `~/.local/share/plasma_notes` folder.

Comment: Now, how do I associate one of those files to the note widget displayed on my desktop after sync with my another machine?